# Angular-UI state transition problems

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-router, state-machine

I am using Angular-UI stateProvider to route between different places in my app. In some places, when I call $state.go('newLocation'), the browser will navigate to the newLocation, but immediately return to where I called it from. So I will literally see the newLocation page for a fraction of a second, then be returned to the previous page.

However, when I refresh the page in my browser, the stateProvider works as it should. Can anyone think of why this would be happening, or what I could be missing.

Thanks!

Comment: Please add some codes.

Answer (score 0):

Without seeing any of your code, I'm going to assume you have a `$state.go('wherever')` in the controller it's navigating to. Check in your `$stateProvider` routing and see which controller is attached to the route you're navigating to.

If there's a reference to `$state.go('wherever')` that is being invoked on controller load, you've found your problem.